# Generating HTML Tables from Tuple Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tuple list of individuals. I would like to generate a HTML table for each person. I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this, but I dont know what that would be. I put together some code that I think is close, but probably not an efficient way of doing it.

Desired Output:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>10</td><td>20</td></tr>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>54</td><td>56</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>20</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>23</td><td>15</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>Sarah</td><td>30</td><td>43</td></tr>
</table>
```

My Code:

```
mytuple = [('Andrew','10','20'),('Jim',"20",'12'),("Sarah","30",'43'),("Jim","23",'15'),("Andrew","54",'56')]
mytuple = sorted(mytuple)
FULL_HTML = ""

for row in mytuple:
     individual_count =  mytuple.count(row[0])
     print individual_count

     for row1 in xrange(row, row + individual_count):
        HTML_BODY "<tr><td>" + row1[0] + "</td><td>" + row1[1] + "</td><td>" + row1[2] + "</td><td></tr>\n"

     FULL_HTML = "<table>\n" _ FULL_HTML + HTML_BODY +"\n</table>\n"

FULL_HTML = "<html>\n" + FULL_HTML + "\n</html>"

print FULL_HTML
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot count the name strings with the `list.count()` method like that; you'd have to loop through all the tuples and manually count. Neither method is efficient anyway.

Although you could simply track what name you output last and add a `</table><table>` line every time you came across a *new* name, the better option is to use the [`itertools.groupby()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to have Python group the names for you:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

mytuple = [('Andrew','10','20'),('Jim',"20",'12'),("Sarah","30",'43'),("Jim","23",'15'),("Andrew","54",'56')]
mytuple = sorted(mytuple)
FULL_HTML = []

for name, rows in groupby(mytuple, itemgetter(0)):
     table = []
     for name, value1, value2 in rows:
        table.append(
            "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td></tr>".format(
                name, value1, value2))

     table = "<table>\n{}\n</table>".format('\n'.join(table))
     FULL_HTML.append(table)

FULL_HTML = "<html>\n{}\n</html>".format('\n'.join(FULL_HTML))

print FULL_HTML
```

The [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) picks out the first element of each tuple to group on.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> mytuple = [('Andrew','10','20'),('Jim',"20",'12'),("Sarah","30",'43'),("Jim","23",'15'),("Andrew","54",'56')]
>>> mytuple = sorted(mytuple)
>>> FULL_HTML = []
>>> for name, rows in groupby(mytuple, itemgetter(0)):
...      table = []
...      for name, value1, value2 in rows:
...         table.append(
...             "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td></tr>".format(
...                 name, value1, value2))
...      table = "<table>\n{}\n</table>".format('\n'.join(table))
...      FULL_HTML.append(table)
... 
>>> FULL_HTML = "<html>\n{}\n</html>".format('\n'.join(FULL_HTML))
>>> print FULL_HTML
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>54</td><td>56</td><td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>20</td><td>12</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>23</td><td>15</td><td></tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td>Sarah</td><td>30</td><td>43</td><td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed and working version of @ravi's answer, since I couldn't edit due to edit queue being full:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list_of_tuples, columns=['name1','name2','name3'])         
html_string = df.to_html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a template engine like Mako (http://www.makotemplates.org/). It's easy and will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively and to follow up Max Noel's suggestions on using a [`mako` template engine](http://www.makotemplates.org/).

Create an `index.html` file with the following contents:

```
<html>
% for _, rows in data:
    <table>
        % for row in rows:
            <tr>
                % for value in row:
                    <td>${value}</td>
                % endfor
            </tr>
        % endfor
    </table>
% endfor
</html>
```

Then, in your python code, [sort](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) `mytuple` by the first element and pass it into the template:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

from mako.template import Template


mytuple = [('Andrew','10','20'),('Jim',"20",'12'),("Sarah","30",'43'),("Jim","23",'15'),("Andrew","54",'56')]
t = Template(filename='index.html')
print t.render(data=groupby(sorted(mytuple), itemgetter(0)))
```

Prints:

```
<html>
    <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Andrew</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>Andrew</td>
                    <td>54</td>
                    <td>56</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Jim</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>Jim</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>15</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Sarah</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>43</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is simple:

```html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(mytuple),columns['name1','name2','name3'])          #name1,name2,name3 are coloumn headings
html = df.to_html("index.html") 
# Create index.html to write html on it
 f = open("index.html","r+")
 data = f.read()
```